# How can I use Rspec to test a controller concern in a ruby gem without rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I think I may be going about this the wrong way. I'm creating a Ruby gem to house some shared functionality. One piece of this functionality is an ActiveSupport::Concern that includes a `before_action` callback. That's looking something like this inside the gem:

```rb
require "active_support"

module MyModule
  module MyConcern
    extend ::ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      before_action :foo
    end

  private

    def foo
      # Some implementation
    end
  end
```

In other words I'm including this in my gem so any codebase using my gem can include the concern on a controller and automatically have the `foo` method run before every action.

That all works fine and dandy so far, but now I'm at the point where I'm trying to test this using plain Rspec and I'm lost. Because my gem doesn't use rails (just ActiveSupport for the concern) I'm not sure how to go about testing this functionality without Rspec-Rails. Usually in a rails app, I'd test the behavior of the controller is working as if `foo` was called before any action, but without Rspec-Rails I don't have access to any way to test controllers.

In addition I'd love a way to create a `shared_example` for this concern that can be used in any app that uses the gem to verify the concern is working correctly on each controller, but again I think that would require having Rspec controller syntax like `get :index` that comes along with Rspec-Rails.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Should I be including Rails in my tiny little gem just so I can test this properly? Am I going about testing this the wrong way? Is it wrong to be including a concern like this in a gem?

Comment: If you're developing the concern as a gem, there's no reason that your gemspec can't install rails and rspec-rails as development dependencies. You can look at PaperTrail's gemspec as an example: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/paper_trail.gemspec

Comment: If you build a Rails engine/plugin then you get a dummy app which you can test I think https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html